# Some CSS Problems

Tags: html, css, bulma

I'm working on a personal project. On road to learning web design and development.

I'm actually working my way through the **Bulma Framework** right now.

So just know that I'm using the Bulma Framework (bulma.io)

So yeah I have been having a few issues.

I have built this:- [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjtMJ.png)

Well, I believe I just got this to work by messing around a lot with positioning and everything. It is not at all responsive, When I resize the window everything just breaks down. I'd like to see how you lot will build it responsively. Note that I'm using columns provided by BULMA to get them aligned next to each other.

This is my code

```
  <div class="columns is-gapless centered">
    <div class="column is-one-quarter">

                  <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/128x128.png" class="mainImg">

                </div>
                <div class="column is-one-quarter">
                  <div class="boxtext">
                    Lorem Ipsum Im dor dor dorLorem Ipsum Im dor dor
                    Lorem Ipsum Im dor dor dorLorem Ipsum Im dor dor dorLorem  
                    Lorem Ipsum Im dor dor dor Lorem Ipsum Im dor dor dor


                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

My CSS for the items I made is: -

```
 .columns.is-gapless.centered {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}
img.mainImg {
    width: 1200px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-bottom: -10%;
    margin-left: 104%;
}

.boxtext {

    position: absolute;
    white-space: pre;
    left: 41%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    color: #000;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-weight: 500;
}
```

Comment: Bulma does all of the positioning and stuff for you, so I think your problems are from setting these properties yourself. Columns and column classes in CSS automatically do the layout so you don't have to. Could you state what your goal is? Is it to layout the image next to the text side by side? This would help us figure out how to help more specifically.

Comment: Yes that exactly is my objective. I have done it as you can see in the image. But its not perfect. I just wanted to know if there is a better method out there of doing what I did. Also what I made is not at all responsive. So yeah I want to see better ways to make it and also responsive ones.

Comment: Take a look at my changes to your code in this jsfiddle, it will show you a better way with less code. Bulma does the heavy lifting of sizing columns for you and all you need to do it make the image fill up the space of the column (which is actually not great, it is better to have the right sized image, or it will get pixelated.) Code here: https://jsfiddle.net/jx1eq0da/